# Powerapps: using Excel DataSource, Screen blank

Tags: powerapps

I'm currently following some steps in youtube, I'm making datatable in excel named `Employee` and `Department` save it to the onedrive.

I'm creating an app, by `start with your data`
[image]

after following the wizard,my app's screen is blank
[image]

my data in excel is 
[image]

**What went wrong ?**
I have search it, but can't seem to find exact problem and solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have each table on a separate sheet.  Take a look at the following video for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z_13J02RPU&t=939s